# How to uncheck the center the page option in layout of the print?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, printing, crystal-reports

I have developed an application for billing purpose and My client is using Thermal Printer for Invoice Billing. My Client has WeB TH400 Thermal Printer and Whenever client go for print he has to follow this path to print

[image: First]
[image: Second]
[image: Third]

How do I remove `Center the Page` check in Crystal report?

Comment: I think you should try to check it by using c#, because it is an option for your printer and is not related to Crystal Reports ;).

Comment: Ok but still how to do that? I'm not getting any solution for it.

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7324887/4519059) can help you ;).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new paper size for the printer, preferably one that is wider than it is high, and do not use the start and end sections of the page, only use the start and end sections of reports, so when it is printed it will not use more paper If the tickets you are going to create are of a fixed size, you can also set the size for them, I have tried many times and I have not found the solution, I have always had to solve it that way

Answer (score 0):

> There are many other proprietary settings defined for printers, so this advice applies to any scenario where you *always* want the users to specify specific settings for single printer.

Instead of trying to *automate* the user actions through C# code, you (or the user) should define a new *Printer Definition* and pre-set the desired settings as the default settings via *Printer Preferences*.

*please excuse my Windows 11 interface, the preference dialog has been in windows in some form since the beginning.*

[image: set printer preferences]

If multiple users are affected the user environment is a Windows Domain then you can define this printer definition as a domain resource and secure it so that users cannot alter the defaults.

> If there is no reason to ever print to this printer using other settings, you can simply set the default properties on the single instance of this printer, however this works well for cases where you have multiple trays or multiple fixed scenarios for the user to choose from, you should use a naming convention that describes the properties that are set by default if the user chooses to print with that printer:
>
> [image: example of printer naming convention]

---

*One of the reasons this post didn't attract much notice is that this solution for printers has been used since long before .Net programming (I remember doing this in the early 90s), it became sort of assumed knowledge, but also many modern printer drivers include variations of *profiles* or *presets* that make this redundant, but the vast number of variations out there in the market make it incredibly hard to code a generic solution from your application, so the developers of the world all sort of gave up and delegated the responsibility of configuring the application printers to the networking and infrastructure guys.*